# CollectionView Styling with Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

So I'm currently building an app using collectionViews. However the next I want the rows to center align. (if that make sense).

As you see on this picture:
[image]

There is a huge white area between the 2 items. Why doens't the second item go right below the 1st one with a white space of like 8px?

Also I want my App to work on iPad and iPhone so scaling is import for me with this app. I was hoping I could just have each row represent 25% of the view area. How would I accomplish this? But still keep it nice/clean and function-able on both iPads and iPhones.

EDIT:
Also if I lower the size so I can fit 3 below each other, they first stack vertically instead of horizontally. Even tho it's a horizontally scrollable collectionview?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal example (i.e. test XCode project).

Answer (score 0):

The white space is because the `UICollectionView` is using the default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Use this method to achieve what you want:

```
func setCollectionLayout()
{
    let totalWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let size = totalWidth * 0.1 // this is how you set item with a proportion of the screen
    let collectionLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    collectionLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: size , height: size)
    collectionLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8
    collectionLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8 , 0 , 8 , 0)
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = collectionLayout
    collectionView.layoutSubviews()
}
```

If you want any further customization you can override `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`